# Select value based on value of another row in mysql

Tags: mysql, select

Is it possible to create a function in mysql that selects a value based on another value in another row of the same table?

given i have 5 columns

```
player1 | player1server | player2 | player2server | winner | reward
john    |    server1    | nick    |   server2     | nick   |  10
```

is it possible to somehow return the server of the winner based on the winner column with a select query?
im very new to mysql so sorry if this is basic stuff but i couldnt find any answers on here that helped me

Comment: something like `select case when winner=payer1 then player1server else player2server end from table`?

Comment: 5 columns? Eh??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify the name of the table, so I'll call it "game".

```
SELECT if (winner = player1, player1server, player2server) FROM game;
```

If the value from winner = the value from player1, then the player1server column will be selected, otherwise the player2server will be selected.

If I were designing this database though, I'd put players in their own table, which would look something like this:

```
| id | name | server  |
|  1 | John | server1 |
|  2 | Nick | server2 |
```

And the game table:

```
| id | player1_id | player2_id | winner_id | reward |
|  1 |          1 |          2 |         2 |     10 |
```

This way, the name and server information for each player isn't being repeated for each row in the game table, and you don't need to use an IF statement in your select. Instead you can do something like the following (selects the game id and winner's server):

```
SELECT g.id, p.server FROM game g LEFT JOIN player p ON g.winner_id = p.id;
```

Comment: Thank you for this.
Yes, im pretty sure it would have been a better idea to do it like you suggested but when i started messing with mysql (like 4 days ago) i didnt even know about the possibility to join tables.
im not sure why i was downvoted tho but thank you alot for helping out!